# NullPointerException for instantiated button in action listener

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, jbutton, actionevent

The following code is a snippet of a program I am getting a nullpointer exception from. When I press the "Add" button on the GUI, an error message pointing to this line:

```
  buttonPanel.addButton.setEnabled(false);
```

is displayed. I'm guessing that the addButton is null for some reason although I instantiated it in the constructor of buttonPanel:

```
 addButton = new JButton("Add");
 addButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
```

Why is the null pointer error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at AddButtonListener.actionPerformed(AddButtonListener.java:21)
```

appearing? When the listener is coded inside the buttonPanel class, the program runs fine with no errors. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{
    public JButton addButton,
                   editButton,
                   deleteButton,
                   acceptButton,
                   cancelButton,
                   exitButton;

    public JPanel topPanel,
                   exitPanel;

    private ParentFrame parentFrame;

    public static String buttonStatus;

    public ButtonPanel(ParentFrame parent){
        parentFrame = parent;

        buttonStatus = "idle";
        //Create Buttons

        AddButtonListener buttonListener = new AddButtonListener(parent);
        addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        acceptButton = new JButton("Accept");
        cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        //Manipulate Buttons
        acceptButton.setEnabled(false);
        cancelButton.setEnabled(false);

        //Add to panels
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(addButton);
        topPanel.add(editButton);
        topPanel.add(deleteButton);
        topPanel.add(acceptButton);
        topPanel.add(cancelButton);

        exitPanel = new JPanel();
        exitPanel.add(exitButton);

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        this.add(topPanel);
        this.add(exitPanel);
    }
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    private ParentFrame myFrame;

    private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    public AddButtonListener(ParentFrame parent){
        myFrame = parent;
        buttonPanel = parent.buttonPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        buttonPanel.buttonStatus = "add";

        buttonPanel.addButton.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPanel.editButton.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPanel.deleteButton.setEnabled(false);

        buttonPanel.acceptButton.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPanel.cancelButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

}

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ParentFrame extends JFrame{

    public ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    public ParentFrame(){
        this.setResizable(false);

        buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(this);

        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.pack();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ParentFrame frame = new ParentFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging this?

Comment: Yes--this error is present for the setEnable() method in all the buttons, and a simple if(buttonPannel.addButton == null){...} check returns the same error in the conditional.

Comment: Check my answer, it explains what's happening and offers a solution. `buttonPanel` is null. Tricky case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buttonpanel requires a reference to `ParentFrame` to be constructed. `ButtonPanel` is being constructed in parent frame and creating a listener, which references the parent frame's button panel.

Unfortunately, the button panel hasn't been assigned at that point, and so your action listener has a null value assigned to its instance of button panel.

I think the problem is your button panel instance is null in your `AddButtonListener`.

You can fix this by passing a ButtonPanel instance into your `AddButtonListener` constructor. As `AddButtonListener` isn't using `ParentFrame`, don't bother passing it at all.

```
private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;
public AddButtonListener(ButtonPanel panel){
    myFrame = parent;
    buttonPanel = panel;
}
```

And then in your button panel constructor:

```
public ButtonPanel(ParentFrame parent){
    parentFrame = parent;

    buttonStatus = "idle";
    //Create Buttons

    AddButtonListener buttonListener = new AddButtonListener(this);
    //rest the code
```

Aside, you shouldn't be structuring things like this. What you're doing is tightly coupling your `ButtonPanel` with your `ParentFrame`. This means if your parent frame changes it could cause another change in `ButtonPanel`, which makes for less maintanable code.

Comment: Yeah... good job tracking that down quickly btw. Pretty tricky. Surprised we noticed it.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I considered that a possibility but was confused because it worked when I put the action listener in the same ButtonPanel class.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the `new AddButtonListener(parent);` before the `ButtonPanel(ParentFrame parent)` is fully  initialized, so all it componets are null.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following
In AddButtonListener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    // change all references to buttonPanel to myFrame.buttonPanel
    myFrame.buttonPanel.buttonStatus = "add";
    ...
}
```

This is because while you construct the ButtonPanel, the buttonPanel variable inside ParentFrame you pass around is null at that very moment.

see

```
public ParentFrame(){
    ...
    // when you initialize this, buttonPanel is null until constructing is complete
    buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(this);
    ...
}
```

Therefore AddButtonListener.buttonPanel is null.

Comment: Good catch, however I'd suggest not using `myFrame` at all in the `AddButtonListener` as its not needed. This reduces `AddButtonListener` dependencies.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Thanks! I was about to write about changing all the classes to not be passing around everything to everyone but then decided to settle on a simpler solution :)

Comment: Cool, be sure to accept someone's answer to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

you might have delete the initialization code which is:

```
public yourClass()
{
    initComponents();
    btn(false);
}
```